# circular buffer using mutex

Tags: c++, boost, circular-buffer

This was from compsci lecture quiz that my professor want us to challenge. he said that this class is about circular buffer but has got major problem. I've try to think for whole day but have no clue. please give me some ideas

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

template <typename T, uint32_t max>
class CircularBuffer
{
public:

    CircularBuffer() : m_WriteOffset(0), m_ReadOffset(0){}
    ~CircularBuffer(){};

    void push( T val )
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard( m_Mutex );
        m_Buffer[m_WriteOffset++] = val;
    }

    T pull()
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard( m_Mutex );
        return m_Buffer[m_ReadOffset++];
    }

private:

    boost::mutex m_Mutex;

    enum { MAX_SIZE = max };
    T m_Buffer[MAX_SIZE];
    uint32_t m_WriteOffset;
    uint32_t m_ReadOffset;
};
```

Comment: To give you a hint: There is a superfluous semicolon in the code. Then, write a test with two threads, one writing N elements with a pattern, the other reading N elements and verifying the pattern.

Comment: You should include `<cstdint>` instead of `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: ...and use std::thread, but that assumes you have a C++11 compiler.

Comment: If you don't know what a `mutex` and what a `lock_guard` is, then better research that first. This is basic knowledge at the level of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`full`, `empty` methods not implemented.
Offset increment must be like `m_ReadOffset = (m_ReadOffset + 1) % MAX_SIZE`, then only the buffer will be circular. Both read and write offset I mean.

Comment: can I ask you how lock_guard works inside of the function? I know how mutex works but not with boost functions.

Comment: sorry that I could not answer your question. I actually don't know C++, just answered the logical part of a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a hint, so here is one:

What happens if you push MAX_SIZE+1 elements before reading any?

Comment: thanks, don't really understand how mutex and lock_guard functions works so I was kind of lost what is the main problem.

Comment: the lock guard just locks the mutex, and unlocks it when it goes out of scope.